# actual and formal argument lists differ in length, but they actually are the same

Tags: java, constructor

So I am trying to create a boxclient to make a box out of points with the following file:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class boxclient{

    public static void main(String[] args){
     Point o = new Point(5,5);
     Point t = new Point(5,5);
     Point r = new Point(5,5);
     Point f = new Point(5,5);

     Box one = new Box(o,t,r,f);
     }

    }
```

That was my client, and this is my box class:

```
import java.awt.Point;


public class Box{
private int x,y;
private int rot;
private int width, height;

private Point[] my = new Point[4];
private Box[] conto = new Box[100];
private int concount = 0;

 public void Box(Point topleft, Point topright, Point botleft, Point botright){
  this.my[0] = topleft;
  this.my[1] = topright;
  this.my[2] = botleft;
  this.my[3] = botright;
  }
```

And I am getting this error for no apparent reason:

1 error found:
File: C:\Users\George\Desktop\2dShooter\boxclient.java  [line: 11]
Error: constructor Box in class Box cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.awt.Point,java.awt.Point,java.awt.Point,java.awt.Point
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Any ideas? I've tried restarting my drjava and saving and compiling and rewriting as the same name a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got confused with *Constructor* and *Method*. Methods have return types atleast *void*. But Constructors **don't** have any return type. They just create the *new instance*.

So,

```
public void Box(Point topleft, Point topright, Point botleft, Point botright){
```

denotes a Method declaration, it will not be recognized as a Constructor. that's why the error is thrown.

You have to declare the *Constructor* with **No** return type, just like the one below

```
public Box(Point topleft, Point topright, Point botleft, Point botright){
```

Now, the Constructor has the correct argument list of `Point` type. There will not be any error now. Hope you understand!

Answer (score 7):

```
public void Box(Point topleft, Point topright, Point botleft, Point botright){
```

That is not the correct way to declare a constructor. Replace that with:

```
public Box(Point topleft, Point topright, Point botleft, Point botright){
```

Comment: The explanation of the specific error message is that the lack of a declared constructor causes the compiler to generate a zero argument constructor, which cannot be called with four arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor. You are here only calling a method.